# Is there a succinct alternative to this `literal as literal` pattern?

Tags: typescript

Frequently when transforming data in Typescript, I run into problems like this where I need to step in and tell the type system something that seems should be obvious to it...

```js
type SomeCompound = {type: 'a', value: number} | {type: 'b', value: string}

const transform = (v: number) => {
    return {type: 'a', value: v};
}

const result: SomeCompound[] = [1,2,3].map(transform);
// ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"b"' (or '"a"', or so on)
```

Here, I *know* whatever comes out of `transform` is going to be of `type: 'a'`... but the type system doesn't seem to understand that.

Possible fixes are to just copy and paste the entire type to the return signature...

```js
const transform = (v: number): {type:'a', value: number} => {
    return {type: 'a', value: v};
}
```

... or to use this pattern, which is the crux of what I'm asking...

```js
const transform = (v:number) => {
    return {type: 'a' as 'a', value: v};
}
```

Either one of those makes it work as expected (no error on the indicated line), but... is there something I've missed? Some piece of syntax I should be using instead of this `literal as literal` pattern? Some signal word that makes the type system try a bit harder?

Usual disclaimers about this being a highly reduced example; the obvious troll rebuke of "what's wrong with either of those?" is that either of these patterns, once scaled up to a thousand instances, represents a code maintenance problem.

Comment: Explicit return types catch an entire class of errors.

Comment: @jsejcksn Explicit return types, in the real case this is reduced from, are an error. I'm searching for a duck-typing solution with less code smell than repeating a literal twice, because in the real situation this is reduced from, `transform` looks more like `export function transform<G,X>(g:G, x:X) { return {...g, extra: x, type: 'a'} }`.

Comment: The correct return type would be [`{ [K in keyof G]: G[K]; } & { extra: X, type: 'a' }`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATgQzAZ2HFBbRAHgHEAaRADQD4AKAcwC5EzEAPJigSiYG9EBtANKIYSANYBTAJ5xgzALpNiQ+QG5EAX0QAyRHwmtUaDuShSADhKYByNNc16AUIkQoJUECiQ8AdH7rkBkZMrKYWVoi21hqqjhqOQA)

Comment: I am aware. I did say that was one of the possible fixes. My question is not "help me design this interface", as that is something that was already done by the client consuming this interface, and I get no say in it. My question was: is there a piece of syntax I am unaware of that could help make this code smell go down, and reduce the fragility of future refactorings when the client inevitably requests them? :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use type aliases and function return types, I guess:

```
type PartA = {type: 'a', value: number};
type PartB = {type: 'b', value: string};

type SomeCompound = PartA | PartA

const transform = (v: number): PartA => {
    return {type: 'a', value: v};
}

const result: SomeCompound[] = [1,2,3].map(transform);
```

Or just `as const` on function return:

```
type SomeCompound = {type: 'a', value: number} | {type: 'b', value: string}

const transform = (v: number) => {
    return {type: 'a', value: v} as const;
}


const result: SomeCompound[] = [1,2,3].map(transform);
```

Comment: `as const` *does* look like the answer I was looking for... *except* that putting it on the entire structure makes the structure fields `readonly` as well, which might not always be acceptable. Writing `'a' as const`, however, fixes the problem of bizarre repetition which brought me here.

Comment: So why not use explicit return types? You should probably show more of your code, this is why "highly reduced examples" sometimes don't work in showing the problem you're looking answers for.